# Incorporating functions in oop

Tags: php, function, oop

I'm trying to write a code for one of my schools assignments, yet I cannot find the reason for it not working. It's probably something simple that i'm yet unaware of. Could anyone point me in the right direction. I'm trying to make a class generate 3 dropdown boxes for selecting the day, month and year. Also there seems to be an infinite loop with the 3rd function. The code is as follows and is split between two files.

File 1: datselect.php

```
<?php

    include ("datselect_functions.php");

    $cls = new Dropdown();

    $monthname = array(1 => "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                     "July","August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

    $today = time(); 
    $f_today = date("M-d-Y",$today);

    $func = insert_day();
    $func = insert_month($monthname);
    //$func = insert_year($today);

    echo html_head($f_today);
    echo $cls -> getHTML();
    echo html_foot();

?>
```

File 2: datselect_functions.php

```
<?php

function html_head($f_today) {
    return "<html>
            <head>
            <title>Select a date</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div>
                Today is ".$f_today."
            </div>";
}

class Dropdown {
    private $name = "";
    private $options = array();
    private $selected = "";

    public function __construct($name = "") {
        $this->name=$name;
    }

    public function setOption($var,$label) {
        $this->options[$var]=$label;
    }

    public function getHTML() {
        $html = "<select name='".$this->name."'>";
        var_dump($this->name);
        foreach($this->options as $var => $label) {
            if ($this->selected=$var) {
                $html.= "<option selected value='".$var."'>.$label.</option>";
            } else {
                $html.= "<option value='".$var."'>.$label.</option>";
            }
        }
        $html.= "</select>";
        return $html;
    }
}

function html_foot() {
return "</body></html>";
}

function insert_day(){
    $ddd = new Dropdown("day");
    for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++){
        $ddd -> setOption($i, $i);
    }
}

function insert_month($monthname){
    $ddm = new Dropdown("month");
    foreach($monthname as $key => $value) {
        $ddm -> setOption($key, $value);
    }
}

function insert_year($today){
    $currentyear = date("Y", $today);
    $ddy = new Dropdown("year");
    for($n=$currentyear;$n=$currentyear+3;$n++) {
        $ddy -> setOption($n, $n);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: The first thing for you to realize: we have no idea what you mean by saying "not working". Any code works. Literally any. Just may be not the way you're expecting.

Comment: can you give us the result or the error message? it usually tells you on what line you are mistaken

Comment: Btw, your `insert_day`, `insert_month` functions make no sense. You're creating an object, modifying its state and then... do nothing with it.

Comment: @kpp It just gives me 1 empty dropdown box and stated the date at the top of the page.

Comment: @zerkms i meant it's not doing what i expected it to do :). Also how do i then get the getHTML() to incorporate the 3 functions listed at the bottom?

Comment: I think you really ought to go back and tell your teacher that you really didn't get that lecture on Classes, and could (s)he help you out.

Comment: I think I found your problem, this concept good but indeed like zerkms said you dont return the html in `insert_day` and `insert_month` add `return $ddd->gethtml();` to all 3 functions and echo the value see if it works then.

Comment: @kpp yes thats a bit closer it now var_dumps the correct name, but does still not use the var and label strings. Lets see if i can find the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of things where it goes wrong.

```
//this is unnecessary, you now create an empty dropdown and echo it here.
$cls = new Dropdown();    
echo $cls -> getHTML();

//instead of this
$func = insert_day();
$func = insert_month($monthname);
//$func = insert_year($today);

//do this
$days = insert_day();
$months = insert_month($monthname);
$years = insert_year($today);

//then make the dropdows appear like this.
echo $days;
echo $months;
echo $years;

//These 3 functions require an extra line of code.
function insert_day(){
    $ddd = new Dropdown("day");
    for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++){
        $ddd -> setOption($i, $i);
    }
    //add this line to all of these three functions, but change the var name
    return $ddd->getHTML();
}
```

This should resolve most of your errors, but now a few others might appear though.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762 also check out this link for more information about oophp,

Comment: do the 3 functions not have to be methods in this case then?

Comment: Never mind, works like a charm! Thanks a bunch, if i had the rep i'd upvote!

Answer (score 0):

"=" is not a comparison but a setting (use "==" instead):

```
if ($this->selected=$var) {
```

Endless-Loop:

```
for($n=$currentyear;$n=$currentyear+3;$n++) {
```

Use this:

```
for($n=$currentyear;$n < $currentyear+3;$n++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Dropdown class is just a helper that generates the dropdown html code. You need to store that generated code or output it somewhere, for "it to work".

```
$func = insert_day(); // 1
$func = insert_month($monthname); // 2
//$func = insert_year($today);

echo html_head($f_today); // 3
echo $cls -> getHTML(); // 4
echo html_foot(); // 5
```

You are doing the following here, step by step:

1. You assign the dropdown html code for the day selection to $func
2. You assign the dropdown html code for the month selection to $func, overwriting everything from 1. You should use a new variable for that or append it with `$func .= insert...` if that's what you want
3. You output your header html
4. You output an empty dropdown, as the Dropdown instance $cls isn't configured anywhere with an options array
5. You output the footer html

What's missing is that you should also output the results from 1. and 2. after 3.
Also the infinite loop in `insert_year` is because you assign the current year + 3 in the for loop, not compare it (`=` vs. `==`).

Also it's good style to have one file per class and nothing else in that, but that shouldn't be the problem here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Back to the drawing board :P

Answer (score 0):

Your insert_day, insert_month functions do not serve any purpose. Below I have updated your code to display the days, although really you dont need so much code.

```
//dateselect.php
<?php

include ("datselect_functions.php");


$cls = new Dropdown();

$monthname = array(1 => "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                   "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

$today = time(); 
$f_today = date("M-d-Y",$today);

$func = $cls->insert_day();
//$func = insert_month($monthname);
//$func = insert_year($today);

echo html_head($f_today);
echo $cls -> getHTML();
//echo html_foot();

?>


//datselect_functions


<?php

function html_head($f_today) {
return "<html>
            <head>
                <title>
                    Select a date
                </title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    Today is ".$f_today."
                </div>";
}

class Dropdown {
private $name = "";
private $options = array();
private $selected = "";

public function __construct($name = "") {
    $this->name=$name;
}

public function setOption($var,$label) {
    $this->options[$var]=$label;
}

public function getHTML() {
    $html = "<select>";
    //var_dump($this->options);
    foreach($this->options as $var => $label) {
        if ($this->selected==$var) {
            $html.= "<option selected value='".$var."'>.$label.</option>";
        }
        else {
        $html.= '<option value="'.$var.'">'.$label."</option>";

        }
    }
    $html.= "</select>";
    //print_r($html);
    return $html;
}

function insert_day(){

for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++){
    $this -> setOption($i, $i);
}
}

function html_foot() {
return "</body></html>";
}


}

function insert_month($monthname){
$ddm = new Dropdown("month");
foreach($monthname as $key => $value) {
    $ddm -> setOption($key, $value);
}
}

function insert_year($today){
$currentyear = date("Y", $today);
$ddy = new Dropdown("year");
for($n=$currentyear;$n<=$currentyear+3;$n++) {
    $ddy -> setOption($n, $n);
}
}

?>
```